# How to pass image URL from from a HTTP server in selenium

Tags: java, selenium

https://saucelabs.com/resources/selenium-file-upload

I am trying to follow the above sample, but I would like to pass the input image file from a HTTP server instead of the local disk. How should I do it? I tried with the HTTP url but it doesn't seem to work as an argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't directly pass a file that is not on your local drive.

but you can do it in 2 steps:

1 - download the file. ex with http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/:

```
FileUtils.copyURLToFile(aRemoteUrl, aLocalFile)
```

2 - upload the local file (as explained in your link)

(you can eventually delete the local file after that)