# selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: File not found while trying to upload image by url through selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, urlretrieve

I need to upload image via external url, i found examples only that shows how to upload locally stored images. This what i tried and this didn't work.

```
driver.find_element_by_id("attachFile_nPaintUploadAll").send_keys("http://bdfjade.com/data/out/89/5941587-natural-image-download.jpg")
```

Error message:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: File not found: http://bdfjade.com/data/out/89/5941587-natural-image-download.jpg
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass image URL from from a HTTP server in selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27839517/how-to-pass-image-url-from-from-a-http-server-in-selenium)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### send_keys(*value)

As per the documentation of [**`send_keys()`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.send_keys) simulates typing into the element.

- **`send_keys(*value)`**
- Args :

  ```
  value - A string for typing. For setting file inputs, this could be a local file path.
  ```
- Use this to set file inputs:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_id("attachFile_nPaintUploadAll").send_keys("path/to/profilepic.gif")
  ```

But as per your code trial as you are passing an *url* as a *string* hence you see the error as:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: File not found: http://bdfjade.com/data/out/89/5941587-natural-image-download.jpg
```

### Solution

If your *usecase* is to use *Selenium* for file uploading you have to have the download the file in your local system and pass the *absolute path* of the file as an argument within `send_keys()` method.

---

### Alternative (urllib.request.urlretrieve)

As an alternative, you can also use [**`urlretrieve`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html?highlight=request#module-urllib.request) method from *Python 3.x* as follows:

### <sub>urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, filename=None, reporthook=None, data=None)</sub>

- Copy a network object denoted by a URL to a local file. If the URL points to a local file, the object will not be copied unless filename is supplied. Return a tuple (filename, headers) where filename is the local file name under which the object can be found, and headers is whatever the info() method of the object returned by `urlopen()` returned (for a remote object). Exceptions are the same as for `urlopen()`.
- Code Block:

  ```
  import urllib.request

  urllib.urlretrieve("http://andrew.com/selfie.jpg", "andrew_selfie.jpg")
  driver.find_element_by_id("attachFile_nPaintUploadAll").send_keys("andrew_selfie.jpg")
  ```

Comment: maybe in Code Block:
`urllib.request.urlretrieve("http://andrew.com/selfie.jpg", "andrew_selfie.jpg")`

Answer (score 1):

Try to get the file first and then upload it:

```
import urllib

urllib.urlretrieve("http://bdfjade.com/data/out/89/5941587-natural-image-download.jpg", "5941587-natural-image-download.jpg")
driver.find_element_by_id("attachFile_nPaintUploadAll").send_keys("5941587-natural-image-download.jpg")
```

To retrieve file in Python 3.X you can try

```
urllib.request.urlretrieve("http://bdfjade.com/data/out/89/5941587-natural-image-download.jpg", "5941587-natural-image-download.jpg")
```

or

```
import requests

with open("5941587-natural-image-download.jpg", "wb") as f:
    f.write(requests.get("http://bdfjade.com/data/out/89/5941587-natural-image-download.jpg").content)
```

You can remove the file then with

```
import os

os.remove("5941587-natural-image-download.jpg")
```