# selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: File not found error while uploading file using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, file-upload, sendkeys

When I use this code it gives error for file uploading in Selenium using Python , Can anyone help me with this?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Users\Archi\PycharmProject\chrome driver\chromedriver")
driver.get("https://www.freshersworld.com/user/register")

driver.implicitly_wait(10)

upload="C://Users/Archi/Downloads/resume testing/Resume testing"
driver.find_element_by_id("file-upload").send_keys("upload")
```

Error:

> selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid
>   argument: File not found : upload

Even I checked from this kind of ways also, then also its showing error.

- `C:/Users/Archi/Downloads/resume testing/Resume testing`
- `C:\Users\Archi\Downloads\resume testing/Resume testing`
- `C:\\Users\Archi\Downloads\resume testing/Resume testing`

Comment: Looks like you have `send_keys("upload")` when you should have `send_keys(upload)` without the quotes.

Comment: thank you for making correct but when i remove quotes then also i get error  selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: File not found :

Comment: sir i think i am using wrong slash / , \  which one should i use . i checked from all ways.. thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close enough.

You don't want to pass the character sequence **upload** through `send_keys()` rather you want to pass the file `C://Users/Archi/Downloads/resume testing/Resume testing`

So you need to make two(2) changes as follows:

- Use a distinct path separator i.e. either `/` or `\\`
- Add the file extension, e.g. `.doc`

So, your effective code block will be:

```
upload="C:\\Users\\Archi\\Downloads\\resume testing\\Resume testing.doc"
driver.find_element_by_id("file-upload").send_keys(upload)
```

---

### Reference

You can find a relevant discussion in:

- [selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: File not found while trying to upload image by url through selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51435570/selenium-common-exceptions-invalidargumentexception-message-file-not-found-whi/51446063#51446063)

Comment: thank you so much. now its working. i added file extension .docx

Answer (score 0):

What language are you using?

For c#, If the path is valid, use the @ symbol and use \

string upload= @"C:\Users\Archi\Downloads\resume testing\Resume testing";

Comment: with python i am using

Comment: Not working for me on C#